# A way to shorten an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an array of four numbers which I need to compare to another array of numbers. I should tell how many of those numbers are right placed, and how many are right numbers but not right placed.

```
F.eks:
Code:    1501
Guess:   1305
Right numbers:    3
Right placement:  2
```

The right placement is easy. But the Right Number part is a bit tricky. This is how I solved it:

```
//Check if number exist in context
        Rn = 0;

        for (int g = 0; g < 4; g++)
        {
            resent[g] = 6;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if 
                    (
                        guess[i] == Numbers[j] 
                     && guess[i] != resent[0] 
                     && guess[i] != resent[1] 
                     && guess[i] != resent[2] 
                     && guess[i] != resent[3]
                    )
                {
                    Rn++;
                    resent[i] = guess[i];
                }
            }

        }
        ConsolePost("Right Numbers: " + Rn);
```

Is there a beter way to do this. Or is it possible to shorten this?

Like:

```
if(guess[i] == Numbers[j] && != resent[0-3])
{
    Something;
}
```

Comment: This should be on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `guess[i] == Numbers[j]  && resent.Take(4).All(r => r != guess[i])` If the length of `resent` ***is*** 4, then you can skip the call to `.All`

Comment: Altough good ideas, I think you're confusing Oskar with all these methods. Make sure he's aware of these extension methods and lambdas and so on. Take a look at the code he's provided. Seems a basic code to me.

Comment: @VasileMarianFălămaș - that's not necessary at all, it's nobody's duty to ensure the OP has a firm understanding of the suggested answers. Although nice, we don't HAVE to show our working out. If he's "confused with all these methods" he can engage in some further reading.

Comment: As a side not you can also use [Intersect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) to see if any numbers match (order or not), `rn = guess.Intersect(Numbers).Count()`.

Comment: @VasileMarianFălămaș : I think that trying to judge the user's ability is an entirely wrong approach to answering questions if it leads to self-censorship. I simply show the way **I** would solve a problem. If the user is left short, they are free to ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Take(4)` and Contains on your `resent` like:

```
!resent.Take(4).Contains(guess[i])
```

So your check could be:

```
if(guess[i] == Numbers[j] && !resent.Take(4).Contains(guess[i]))
```

See: [`Enumerable.Take<TSource> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
>   sequence.

If `resent` size is always 4, then you can skip `Take(4)` and instead just use `Contains` like:

```
if(guess[i] == Numbers[j] && !resent.Contains(guess[i]))
```

Comment: If `resent[]` is always of size 4, you can omit the `.Take(4)` of course.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, yes, I should add that to my answer

Comment: **YES** Just what i needed^^ Thank you ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use Any() to check if you decide to change the size of your array:

```
!resent.Any(c=>c==guess[i])
```

Comment: Haha^^ thisone worked thank you. But not what i needed^^